# Как выводить единицы измерения в опенкарт?

Tags: opencart

Подскажите как выводить единицы измерения для опенкарт 2.3. Когда товар был в граммах, я просто дописывала после вывода веса - гр. А теперь мне нужно чтобы еще выводились и литры, и этот костыль себя изжил. Как обратится к переменной которая отвечает за вывод единиц (гр, кг, л)??

Вот так раньше выводила вес))

```
<?php if($product['weight']>0) { ?>
    <div class="weight">
        <?php echo $product['weight']; ?>гр.
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Мне не совсем понятно для чего вообще нужен был костыль с гр. если в настройках (Система-Локализация-Единицы веса) можно указать любую интересующую вас единицу. 
1) Добавляете новую единицу "веса" - литры.
2) Изменяете в карточке товара граммы/килограммы на литры.
3) Система-Настройки-Локализация - в поле вес указываете литры[image: Литр фотоаппаратов].

Comment: Добрый день. Проблема в том что по умолчанию единицы измерения не отображаются в шаблоне. Шаблон стандартный. У меня выводится  вес в модулях, категориях и карточке товара. Прикрепил фото к вопросу, чтобы было понятнее.

Comment: Я не знаю как реализован вывод (weight) в ваших контроллерах сейчас. Но судя по всему немного не правильно раз приходится дописывать (гр.) 
Должно быть что-то на подобие этого:
 $data['weight'] = $this->weight->format($this->cart->getWeight(), $this->config->get('config_weight_class_id'), $this->language->get('decimal_point'), $this->language->get('thousand_point'));

Comment: (Пример взят из контроллера корзины)
Фишка в том, что в вид передается не просто число, а строка с единицей измерения (гр. кг. л.)

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

Сперва набейте в базу все единицы измерения веса и объёма, которые будут использоваться на сайте, все они будут доступны для выбора во вкладке `Data`, в селекте `Weight Class`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Редактируете запрос в методе `getProduct()` класса `ModelCatalogProduct` (`catalog/model/catalog/product.php`), в начале запроса добавить `wcd.unit as wc_unit`,

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT *, wcd.unit as wc_unit, ...
```

Далее, в этом же запросе, перед последним `WHERE` добавляете `join` на таблицу с юнитами мер весов

```
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "weight_class_description wcd ON (wcd.weight_class_id = p.weight_class_id)
```

Далее, в классе `ControllerProductCategory` (`catalog/controller/product/category.php`) добавляете вес в цикле формирования продуктов:

```
$data['products'][] = array(
    ...     
    'weight' => (float)$result['weight'] . $result['weight_unit']
);
```

И выводите просто - `<?= $product['weight'] ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Кирилл, все верно только еще момент для `(catalog/model/catalog/product.php)`, в этом же методе `getProduct()` там где формируется массив

```
if ($query->num_rows) {
            return array(...
```

добавить ключ и передать значение

```
            'weight_unit'      => $query->row['unit'],
```

Тогда все отработает корректно